# Wick editor alert function with interval continuing after stopped

Tags: javascript

When running my wick editor project with a interval based timer system it will continue to call alerts even when the project has been paused. (This will not continue forever for me but will last a while) I'm curious if the is a bug with wick editor or something else.
This is the code I used for the timer

```
    let inter = setInterval(interV,1000);
    function interV(){
        alert("This code will run every second.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the interval Like this:

```
clearInterval(inter);
```

Or for executing onece, just use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(interV, 1000);
```